# "Telerik / RadTreeView": Multi Table binding Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, entity-framework-6, radtreeview

I use Telerik component (RadTreeView) in winforms with Entity Framework 6 . I config it as is:

```
radTreeView1.DataSource = db.Projects.ToList();

radTreeView1.DisplayMember = "Name1\\Name2";
radTreeView1.ValueMember = "Id1\\Id2";
radTreeView1.ChildMember = "Projects\\ProjectItems";
```

When I add new record to a table Programmeically, `radTreeView1` won't update. even i use this:

```
db.SaveChanges();
radTreeView1.Update();
radTreeView1.Refresh();
```

I have change my code to this :

```
radTreeView1.DataSource = null;
db.SaveChanges();
radTreeView1.DataSource = db.Projects.ToList();
```

`radTreeView1` is updated when i edit a record, or add new record to `ProjectItems` table.
but this error is happen when i add new record to `Projects` table.

```
Error:
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
>       occurred in System.dll
>
> Exception:Thrown: "Property accessor 'ProjectItems' on object 
>       'ProjectControl.DAL.Project' threw the following exception:'Object does not 
>       match target type.'" (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
>       A System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was thrown: "Property accessor 
>       'ProjectItems' on object 'ProjectControl.DAL.Project' threw the following 
>       exception:'Object does not match target type.'"

can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide `ProjectControl.DAL.Project` class content including `RadTreeView` configuration? There is a property named `ProjectItems` which throwing reflection exception, in which line actually the exception has thrown?

Comment: Why app is restarted, Exception isn't happen and new records is display in "RadTreeView" correctly.